# Easiest way to use Facebook API JSON for my website (which language and how to syntax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i must start by saying i only know how to comfortably work with HTML and CSS.

Which would be the easiest way to take the image sources from this, which i'm assuming is a JSON call, http://graph.facebook.com/103184243098195/photos?fields=source&limit=999 and stick them into my HTML in a way that i could format them with CSS?

i have picked around the internet to find out how to do this using jquery and found a few snippets of example code but i do not know how to tell, i'm assuming javascript, what to look for, how to find it and then where to put what it found, ie., the image sources.

i think i need at least this:

var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/103184243098195/photos?fields=source&limit=999';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
});

but i don't know what to put in-between to grab the image sources and then plug them into, let's say, just a div in general. everywhere i go to try and learn which syntax i would need uses terms i do not understand as i am unfamiliar with most languages. i don't even know if this is the right start/direction.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used this API whatsoever, but this should at least give you a start until someone else comes along. :P

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="facebook-stuff"/>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/103184243098195/photos?fields=source&limit=999',     function(url) {
    var data = url.data;
    var paging = url.paging;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
         $('#facebook-stuff').append('<img src="' + data[i].source + '" class="facebook-pics" id="pic' + i + '"/>');   
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zV99P/

Basically, the parameter passed into your function is your JSON object. Data is an array of objects(within that object) from which you can extract the id, source and time of creation from. Using Jquery or just plain javascript you can dynamically create img elements with the source attribute and append them to any element created on the page. There's also a pagination object here if you are looking to split your images across multiple pages. As far as I can understand it from a quick look, you'd have to lower your limit at the end of your query string to a lower number, i.e: ?limit=5, and then you could create previous or next links from the paging object, with paging.previous or paging.next.

Comment: I'm trying this out and it all seems to work very well and i can't thank you enough! looking at the code you provided also gives me a lot of information and i can put it all together to get a good idea of how to get information from a JSON. awesome!